# How can I remove indices of non-max values that correspond to duplicate values of separate list from both lists?

Tags: list, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary, duplicates

I have two lists, the first of which represents times of observation and the second of which represents the observed values at those times. I am trying to find the maximum observed value and the corresponding time given a rolling window of various length. For example-sake, here are the two lists.

```
# observed values
linspeed = [280.0, 275.0, 300.0, 475.2, 360.1, 400.9, 215.3, 323.8, 289.7]

# times that correspond to observed values
time_count = [4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 8.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 14.0, 16.0]

# actual dataset is of size ~ 11,000
```

The missing times (ex: 3.0) correspond to an observed value of zero, whereas duplicate times correspond to multiple observations to the floored time. Since my window will be rolling over the `time_count` (ex: max value in first 2 hours, next 2 hours, 2 hours after that; max value in first 4 hours, next 4 hours, ...), I plan to use an array-reshaping routine. However, it's important to set up everything properly before, which entails finding the maximum value given duplicate times. To solve this problem, I tried the code just below.

```
def list_duplicates(data_list):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    seen_twice = set(x for x in data_list if x in seen or seen_add(x))
    return list(seen_twice)

# check for duplicate values
dups = list_duplicates(time_count)
print(dups)
>> [8.0, 10.0]

# get index of duplicates
for dup in dups:
    print(time_count.index(dup))
>> 2
>> 4
```

When checking for the index of the duplicates, it appears that this code will only return the index of the first occurrence of the duplicate value. I also tried using `OrderedDict` via module `collections` for reasons concerning code efficiency/speed, but dictionaries have a similar problem. Given duplicate keys for non-duplicate observation values, the first instance of the duplicate key and corresponding observation value is kept while all others are dropped from the dict. Per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python?rq=1), my second attempt is just below.

```
for dup in dups:
    indexes = [i for i,x in enumerate(time_count) if x == dup]
print(indexes)
>> [4, 5, 6] # indices correspond to duplicate time 10s but not duplicate time 8s
```

I should be getting `[2,3]` for `time in time_count = 8.0` and `[4,5,6]` for `time in time_count = 10.0`. From the duplicate time_counts, `475.2` is the `max linspeed` that corresponds to duplicate `time_count 8.0` and `400.9` is the `max linspeed` that corresponds to duplicate `time_count 10.0`, meaning that the other linspeeds at leftover indices of duplicate time_counts would be removed.

I'm not sure what else I can try. How can I adapt this (or find a new approach) to find all of the indices that correspond to duplicate values in an efficient manner? Any advice would be appreciated. (PS - I made numpy a tag because I think there is a way to do this via numpy that I haven't figured out yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into the details of how to implement and efficient rolling-window-maximum filter; reducing the duplicate values can be seen as a grouping-problem, which the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) provides efficient and simple solutions to:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
unique_time, unique_speed = npi.group_by(time_count).max(linspeed)
```

For large input datasets (ie, where it matters), this should be a lot faster than any non-vectorized solution. Memory consumption is linear and performance in general NlogN; but since time_count appears to be sorted already, performance should be linear too.

Comment: I have yet to familiarize myself with groupby, though the examples I've seen show how useful it is. The posted solution works for my large dataset, but I always appreciate learning alternative methods and tips; thanks!

Comment: I found the [associated package index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy-indexed) and the [associated github page](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP), but it would really help if there were docs with example usage of various functions (similar to numpy/scipy docs). Is there any related documentation that I have not found yet?

Comment: I ask because I would like to know the indices of the original array (in this case, `linspeed`) that are used or omitted when finding the maximum value per duplicate such that the same indices can be used in other arrays.

Comment: group_by also has an argmax attribute. But indeed you are correct, nice docs would be helpful, but I havnt got around to it. I would be happy to review a PR though :). Also, the code is pretty clean and all the function level docstrings are quite comprehensive, so searching the repo or doing go-to-definition in your IDE should work quite alright.

Comment: I haven't learned how to do PRs yet, but I plan to within the next 3-4 months and can let you know when I do. Thanks btw, your tip about `argmax` being an attribute came in handy.

Answer (score 1):

OK, if you want to do this with numpy, best is to turn both of your lists into arrays:

```
l = np.array(linspeed)
tc = np.array(time_count)
```

Now, finding unique times is just an `np.unique` call:

```
u, i, c = np.unique(tc, return_inverse = True, return_counts = True)

u
Out[]: array([  4.,   6.,   8.,  10.,  14.,  16.])

i
Out[]: array([0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int32)

c
Out[]: array([1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1])
```

Now you can either build your maximums with a `for` loop

```
m = np.array([np.max(l[i==j]) if c[j] > 1 else l[j] for j in range(u.size)])

m
Out[]: array([ 280. ,  275. ,  475.2,  400.9,  360.1,  400.9])
```

Or try some 2d method.  This could be faster, but it would need to be optimized.  This is just the basic idea.

```
np.max(np.where(i[None, :] == np.arange(u.size)[:, None], linspeed, 0),axis = 1)
Out[]: array([ 280. ,  275. ,  475.2,  400.9,  323.8,  289.7])
```

Now your `m` and `u` vectors are the same length and include the output you want.

Comment: And here I was playing with `np.argmax`... I will have a chance to test/play this in about 2 hours, thanks.

Comment: This solution is quadratic in both time and memory; given that timeseries such as described can get very large, it may not be the best solution.

Comment: True, though it could possibly be optimized with sparse arrays.  Depends on the dataset, what will be worthwhile - and a `for` loop will also be very slow if the timeseries is long.