# How to obtain the indices of all maximum values in array A that correspond to unique values in array B?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, duplicates, max, unique

Suppose one has an array of observation times `ts`, each of which corresponds to some observed value in `vs`. The observation times are taken to be the number of elapsed hours (starting from zero) and can contain duplicates. I would like to find the indices that correspond to the maximum observed value per unique observation time. **I am asking for the indices as opposed to the values, [unlike a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43798438/how-can-i-remove-indices-of-non-max-values-that-correspond-to-duplicate-values-o/43842121#comment81945017_43842121) I asked several months ago.** This way, I can apply the same indices on various arrays. Below is a sample dataset, which I would like to use to adapt a code for a much larger dataset.

```
import numpy as np
ts = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10])
vs = np.array([500, 600, 550, 700, 500, 500, 450, 800, 900, 700, 600, 850, 850, 900, 900, 900])
```

My current approach is to split the array of values at any points at which there is not a duplicate time.

```
condition = np.where(np.diff(ts) != 0)[0]+1
ts_spl = np.split(ts, condition)
vs_spl = np.split(vs, condition)

print(ts_spl)
>> [array([0, 0]), array([1]), array([2]), array([3, 3, 3]), array([4, 4]), array([5]), array([6]), array([7]), array([8, 8]), array([9]), array([10])]

print(vs_spl)
>> [array([500, 600]), array([550]), array([700]), array([500, 500, 450]), array([800, 900]), array([700]), array([600]), array([850]), array([850, 900]), array([900]), array([900])]
```

In this case, duplicate max values at any duplicate times should be counted. Given this example, the returned indices would be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15]
# indices = 4,5,6 correspond to values = 500, 500, 450 ==> count indices 4,5
# I might modify this part of the algorithm to return either 4 or 5 instead of 4,5 at some future time
```

Though I have not yet been able to adapt this algorithm for my purpose, I think it must be possible to exploit the size of each previously-split array in `vs_spl` to keep an index counter. Is this approach feasible for a large dataset (10,000 elements per array before padding; 70,000 elements per array after padding)? If so, how can I adapt it? If not, what are some other approaches that may be useful here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

70,000 isn't that insanely large, so yes it should be feasible. It is, however, faster to avoid the splitting and use the `.reduceat` method of relevant ufuncs. `reduceat` is like reduce applied to chunks, but you don't have to provide the chunks, just tell `reduceat` where you would have cut to get them. For example, like so

```
import numpy as np


N = 10**6
ts = np.cumsum(np.random.rand(N) < 0.1)
vs = 50*np.random.randint(10, 20, (N,))

#ts = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10])
#vs = np.array([500, 600, 550, 700, 500, 500, 450, 800, 900, 700, 600, 850, 850, 900, 900, 900])


# flatnonzero is a bit faster than where
condition = np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(ts)) + 1, len(ts)]
sizes = np.diff(condition)
maxima = np.repeat(np.maximum.reduceat(vs, condition[:-1]), sizes)
maxat = maxima == vs
indices = np.flatnonzero(maxat)
# if you want to know how many maxima at each hour
nmax = np.add.reduceat(maxat, condition[:-1])
```

Comment: Currently on mobile. I can test and play with this in about an hour. Thanks!

Comment: I think I follow everything except for the line `condition = np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(ts)) + 1, len(ts)]`. To my understanding, `np.flatnonzero` returns the indices chronologically for values that are not zero, which you check against consecutive times of observation. And your tip about `.reduceat` was helpful. From the docs, I see `np.r_` can build up arrays, but can you explain its usage in this line?

Comment: the `flatnonzero` does exactly the same as the `where` in your code. `r_` applied to vectors and scalars just concatenates them, so in this case we add a zero at the left and the length at the right. That way we do  not only have the inner boundaries but also the outer ones. This is useful, for example when one wants to compute the sizes of the chunks as we do in the next line.